# Should we flag questions with incorrectly accepted answers for moderator attention?

Tags: discussion

Take for example [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/607/find-the-factorial?rq=1). The top answer is pretty great, and as such it has received a lot of votes. But it is **not** the winning answer.

Should we flag such questions for moderator attention? If not, what else should we do?

Comment: Note that in some cases, the OP might have accepted a winning answer that was later beaten. I think that this is fine as long as the contest was open for a reasonable amount of time. OP's should not be required to re-accept every time a new winning answer comes along.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies: Good point. Someone who posted a challenge 4 years ago and accepted an answer that was beaten yesterday probably shouldn't be expected to care.

Comment: @AlexA. Right. Very old challenges can be considered 'retired' and should not be expected to be updated. It's a hassle for the OP and possibly confusing for others who are used to seeing the old answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies And if the authors of said old challenges _do_ still care, they have probably already taken note of the new answer.

Answer (score 16):

No, you should not. There is nothing a moderator can do in this situation that you cannot, and the flag would be declined as "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that **requires** their intervention" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 9):

## Do nothing

Take no action at all. As long as the challenge was open for a reasonable amount of time, there's no need to intervene.

Comment: +1 from me (can't vote)

Answer (score 8):

## Don't flag them, leave a comment

Leave a comment for the OP informing them that another answer has won per their set challenge guidelines.

Comment: The OP will already have received a notification of the new answer, so although it doesn't hurt to leave a comment, it seems redundant if the OP isn't already interested in new answers.

Comment: @trichoplax Agreed.

Answer (score -12):

## Flag them

This would require a custom moderator flag.

Comment: -1 from me (can't vote)