# Is it all right to edit challenge to recognize the winner?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

I know that the best answer in a code golf challenge should be the accepted one. Is it a good idea to add a "final positions table" to the end of the post once a winner is found?

Something like this:

```
Congratulations! Final positions:
    1. FooLang, 25 bytes, by JohnDoe
    2. BarLang, 37 bytes, by JaneDoe
    3. BazLang, 59 bytes, by JackDoe
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Code golf challenges have no defined endpoint.

In the early days of CGCC, we would often write challenges with a defined time limit in mind; e.g. "This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer after one week wins". Now, time limits have largely been relegated to tags where they're necessary (some challenges tagged [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers), etc.), with the idea that a challenge should be valuable to future golfers. Indeed, as new languages and golfing strategies have been developed, old challenges have been revived with many answers that couldn't have existed years ago.

Some have argued that even accepting answers discourages people from participating. Announcing the winner in the question itself is a step too far. And if you were thinking of continuously updating the leaderboard for all eternity, it's much better to include the [Stack Snippet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world) leaderboard in your question. Or, people can just use [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6772/ppcg-design-userscript).

See also:

[What's the "accepted answer"?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8706/whats-the-accepted-answer)

[Are questions in which no answer is the best allowed?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/are-questions-in-which-no-answer-is-the-best-allowed)

Comment: Some cops-and-robbers challenges are also open ended, and some king-of-the-hill contests stay open to new entrants and edits to old answers, depending on the person running the contest.

Comment: Note that many KoTH challenges will include a *leaderboard* which may or may not be updated long after it was posted and other challenges might include an end-date or some other criterion for an "absolute" winner (in this case simply referring to the checkmark being awarded). But new answers are still very much welcome.